# Reference a frame in beamerarticle

Tags: cross-referencing, beamerarticle

In beamer, one can give a label to a frame as an optional parameter. However, this very label is not defined, if the `beamerarticle` class is used. Is there any way to archive a frame reference there? (reason: I want to create lecture notes that refers to certain slides, without ).
MWE (or better, non-working example):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[label=foo]
    Foo
\end{frame}

As seen at Slide~\ref{foo} (in this lecture notes at page \pageref{foo}): Foo.
\end{document}
```

Comment: See section 21.2.3 "Including Slides from the Presentation Version in the Article Version" in the beamer manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `normal` LaTeX `label`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}\label{foo}
    Foo
\end{frame}

As seen at Slide~\ref{foo} (in this lecture notes at page \pageref{foo}): Foo.
\end{document}
```